# find a folder nested in a folder

Tags: macos, applescript, bash

I need to find a folder nested in a folder.

example:

```
/Volumes/"4T Virtual Machines"/outerfolder/innerfolder

mac $ pwd
/Volumes/4T Virtual Machines
mac $ ls -lR outerfolder/
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 mac  staff     0B Aug 28 18:02 file1
-rw-r--r--  1 mac  staff     0B Aug 28 18:02 file2
drwxr-xr-x  5 mac  staff   170B Aug 28 18:04 innerfolder/
drwxr-xr-x  3 mac  staff   102B Aug 28 18:07 otherfolder/

outerfolder//innerfolder:
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 mac  staff     0B Aug 28 18:04 aaa
-rw-r--r--  1 mac  staff     0B Aug 28 18:04 bbb
-rw-r--r--  1 mac  staff     0B Aug 28 18:04 ccc

outerfolder//otherfolder:
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 mac  staff     0B Aug 28 18:07 justskip
mac $
```

Let's have two cases the outerfolder is at the root of the external drive and the outerfolder isn't at the root of the external drive.  I should be able to modify one solution to the other.

I'm writing in applescript on macOS yosemite or later, but potentially invoking a Unix command from applescript. So the solution may be in all applescript or Unix command called from applescript.  The Unix command approach

Here is the Unix command I have for finding the outer folder:

```
find /Volumes -type d -maxdepth 1 ! -name Volumes -exec find {} -type d -maxdepth 1 -name "Virtual Box" \;
```

I tired a third nested find, but errored out

```
 find /Volumes -type d -maxdepth 1 ! -name Volumes -exec find {} -type d -maxdepth 1 -name "Virtual Box" -exec find {}  -type d -maxdepth 1 ! -name inner  \;
find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"
find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"
find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"
mac RC=1   $
```

Comment: So what you basically want to do is to find a folder `innerfolder` which is directly within `outerfolder`, right?

Comment: yes.  But not in the startup drive.

Comment: What makes you think it matters on which drive it is? The filesystem in Unix systems has a common root for all volumes/drives

Comment: because the specification says the file directories will be on an external drive.  I guess it doesn't make any difference in reality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite sure of what you are looking for but the following will list all directories named "Virtual Box" starting with the deepest nested to the least.

```
find /Volumes -type d ! -name Volumes -name "Virtual Box" 2>/dev/null
```

EDIT: OK, understanding your requirement a bit better we can use the `path` predicate to match `outerfolder/innerfolder`

```
find /Volumes -type d -path '*outerfolder/innerfolder'
```

Comment: 2>/dev/null  I assume your trying to get rid of the errors, but it's getting rid of everything.

Comment: I think -name /Volumes and -name Volumes are the same. What is the diff if not?

Comment: @historystamp Well, `2>/dev/null` is sending standard error to the bit bucket and nothing else. Actually, `-name Volumes` will exclude `/Volumes` from the output, my mistake, will edit

Comment: Works now. I had a function named "find" which was confusing things.

Comment: Thanks for the -path example.  I tried using -path on my own but I got errors.  Your solution works!

Comment: @historystamp ...and what do we do when someone gives us a solution that works?

Comment: @CJK Was that a hint?

Comment: I combined solutions.  Where should I show my final solutions: original post or new answer?

Comment: @historystamp It was, yes.  But well done, you got it.  I think either by editing the original post or by posting a new answer are both logical and commonly-used choices.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `innerfolder` needs to be directly within `outerfolder`:

```
find /Volumes -type d -name "outerfolder" -exec test -d {}/"innerfolder" \; \
                                          -exec echo {}/"innerfolder" \;
```

(formatted for readabiliy, you can also put everything on one line and remove the trailing `\` from the first line)

Answer (score 0):

Running fd0's solution:

```
find /Volumes -type d -path '*outerfolder/innerfolder'
```

You get the annoying "Permission denied" messages.  You could send all error messages to /dev/null, but that's too drastic to me.

```
find: /Volumes/4T Virtual Machines/.DocumentRevisions-V100: Permission denied
find: /Volumes/4T Virtual Machines/.TemporaryItems: Permission denied
find: /Volumes/4T Virtual Machines/.Trashes: Permission denied
/Volumes/4T Virtual Machines/outerfolder/innerfolder
/Volumes/4T Virtual Machines/outerfolder/otherfolder/outerfolder/innerfolder
mac RC=1   $
```

I combined fd0 answer with a previous poster's way of getting rid of permission's errors.

```
 { LC_ALL=C find /Volumes -type d -path '*outerfolder/innerfolder'  3>&2 2>&1 1>&3 | grep --color=auto -v -e 'Permission denied' -e 'Operation not permitted' 1>&3; [ $? = 1 ];  } 3>&2 2>&1


/Volumes/4T Virtual Machines/outerfolder/innerfolder
/Volumes/4T Virtual Machines/outerfolder/otherfolder/outerfolder/innerfolder
```

The downside of using the find command is that it takes a long while should you include the timemachine backup disk.